# How can I force UIPath to "refresh" my window?

Tags: rpa, uipath, jxbrowser

I've been creating a smoke test for a complicated custom application that checks whether basic UIPath functionality works with the application's UI, as there have been problems in the past, creating complaints from customers that use UIPath for automation.

Unfortunately, during my smoke test, UIPath repeatedly doesn't recognize changes in the UI. For example, my UIPath script performs some actions on one page, then presses a return button in the application to return to an overview page. However, when it tries to subsequently select an element on the overview page, it reproducibly does not find the element, and instead lists elements from the previously-navigated-away-from page as the closest match. This suggests to me that UIPath is working with an outdated cached copy of the UI.

I suspect that the reason these problems occur might be related to the complexity of the SUT, which was not originally designed to render web pages. It's therefore using the Chromium-based JxBrowser to render such content. However, I can't seem to be able to get UIPath to recognize it as a browser, and as the displayed content is a single page application, an "F5-refresh" wouldn't be particularly helpful anyway. Unfortunately, I can't find another "refresh" functionality that I could use in my script.

**That being said, I'm hoping that there is some functionality in UIPath that allows me to manually tell UIPath to update its model of the window "DOM".** Hopefully, this would allow me to either fix the issue, or to at least determine if the error could be caused by the application under test instead of by UIPath.

Comment: Have you gone down the route of utilizing the Check App State and ensuring the UI matches what you expect? Might be worth obtaining the Element Details of the page and looking at the specific UI element. Then atleast you could extract out the data you need, pop it into a variable and retry the element with the variable in the element details.

Comment: JxBrowser is based on Chromium, so UIPath should work with JxBrowser exactly as in Google Chrome/Chromium. I recommend that you check your case with Chrome/Chromium first. If you see that JxBrowser behaves differently, then please contact JxBrowser Support at https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/getting-help/ for assistance.